# how to count values from an array and show value only once in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, counting

I am struggling with this problem:
I have an array with months as values. In the array are 3 values(months): `09`, `09` and `04`. So 2 times the month September (09) and 1 time the month April (04).

Now i want to output each month only once and the number of times that the month occurs behind it.
So my output in this should look like

```
04 1 // april 1 time
09 2 // september 2 times
```

I now have this foreach loop:

```
$months = array('04','09','09');
foreach($months as $month) {                
    $archive_months = array('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'); 
    $counts = array_count_values($archive_months);
    echo $month.' '.$counts[$month].'<br />';
```

if i use `foreach(array_unique($months) as $month) {` the month september (09) appears only once but the number is 1 and not 2.

Output:

```
04 1
09 1
```

And it should be:

```
04 1
09 2
```

Comment: you count the number of time `09` is in  `archive_months` => 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count values of months not archive_months

```
<?php

$months = array('04','09','09');
 
$counts = array_count_values($months);
var_dump($counts);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["04"]=>
  int(1)
  ["09"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not counting `$months`, but `$archive_months`.

And `arry_count_values` is already doing what you need. No for loop needed.

```
$months = array('04','09','09');
print_r(array_count_values($months));
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Ôrel already mentioned:

```
$months = array('04','09','09'); 
$counts = array_count_values($months);

// your foreach:
foreach($counts as $key => $val) {
    echo $key.' '.$val.'<br />';
}
```

Output will be something like:

```
09 2
04 1
```